# MVC KENDO UI GRID - dynamic columns objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, telerik-grid

Hi there im building a grid that have dynamic columns depending on the number of a specific object.. here's a example

```
   public class Team
   {
       string name {get;set;}
       List<members> memberslist {get;set;}
     }

     public class member{
       string name {get;set;}
       int goals {get;set;}
      }
```

in the view:

```
      @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.TeamList)
        .Name("goalslist")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(team => team.name).Title("Team Name");
            columns.Bound(team => team.memberslist);

        }...
```

what i would like the result was something like this:

Team Name,   John Smith      Taylor       Fernandez    
Ajax                22                   1                 3  
Milan               0                   1                  2

Any Ideia?! how its done will print object[object], i tried a lot of stufs but without sucess.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is through JSON.  Convert your column list into json and pass it to the column, see below.  At the very bottom you can see me pushing the columns to the grid.  Below that you can see what the JSON itself looks like.

```
  var gridJSON = {
        dataSource: {
            data: data,
            schema: {
                model: {} // the model gets filled in by the JSON coming from the database
            },
            pageSize: 20
        },
        height: 550,
        groupable: false,
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true,
        filterable: {
            extra: false,
            operators: {
                string: {
                    startswith: "Starts with",
                    eq: "Is equal to",
                    neq: "Is not equal to"
                }
            }
        },
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 5
        },
        toolbar: kendo.template($("#template").html())
    };

    gridJSON.columns = currentReport.JSON.columns;
    gridJSON.dataSource.schema.model.fields = currentReport.JSON.fields;
```

Here is the JSON for the 'currentReport.JSON.columns'

```
"columns" : [{
            "field" : "ReceiverID",
            "title" : "Receiver ID"
            }, {
            "field" : "ReceiverBatchID",
            "title" : "Batch ID"
            }, {
            "field" : "PoNumber",
            "title" : "PO Number"
            }, {
            "field" : "ReceiverTransactionDate",
            "title" : "Receiver Trans Date",
            "format" : "{0: yyyy-MM-dd}"
            }, {
            "field" : "PrintingLocation",
            "title" : "Location"
            }, {
            "field" : "VendorID",
            "title" : "Vendor ID"
            }, {
            "field" : "InNemo",
            "title" : "InNemo"
            }, {
            "field" : "Path",
            "title" : "Path",
            "encoded" : "true",
            "template": "#=Path#",
            "width" : "50"
        }
    ]
```